# Python OpenCV - Detect hands

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

We all love haar cascades.

Moreover, in Python OpenCV **detecting faces** in an input image is pretty straightforward:

```
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread("picture.jpg", 0)
haar_face = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_face)
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
```

[image]

But how do I **detect hands** following the exact same approach?

I've searched, downloaded and used a lot of xml files from the internet but they all perform really poorly.

**Could anyone point out a good reference of xml haarcascade file for hand detection**?

Answer (score 1):

Using haarcascades for hand detection will not give very robust detection results because of the different possible poses of the hand. So open hand or fist will need separate haarcascades. Although haarcascades cannot handle rotation very well.

If your hardware allows it you could use deep neural networks to detect the hands.
Very robust approach is to detect the body pose and extract the hand keypoints from there:

Very robust but also very resource hungry/slow (GPU is a must):
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

Less accurate but much faster:
https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation

Just new and promising, but untested for me:
https://github.com/tensorlayer/openpose-plus

Answer (score 0):

Use a corresponding haarcascades file. There isn't one in the [stock set](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) but someone has made a custom set at https://github.com/Balaje/OpenCV/tree/master/haarcascades . (Disclaimer: I didn't test it.)